# Do tidal forces create atmospheric jet streams?

Tags: atmospheric-science, tidal-effect, weather

Earth's large-scale wind patterns (a.k.a. jet streams) are generally attributed to "differential heating" by the sun.

But the large-scale patterns in Earth's oceans (a.k.a. tides and tidal currents) are attributed to tidal forces, primarily between Earth and its moon.  [The tidal force gradient looks something like this](https://www.lockhaven.edu/%7Edsimanek/scenario/tides101.htm):
[image: Tidal forces]

Tidal forces produce tidal bulges not only in the oceans but also in the earth itself.

Do the tidal forces also produce a "bulge" in the atmosphere?  If so, do those atmospheric bulges contribute to jet streams, or are they dwarfed by the magnitude of winds produced by differential heating?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Applied_to_the_Earth  and of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tidecourse

Comment: @annav The second link is invalid, and a general search for "atmospheric tidecourse" finds nothing.  Regarding the Coriolis effect: it appears to be a separate, second-order influence on "the large-scale dynamics of the oceans and the atmosphere."

Comment: sorry, I missprinted it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tide#Lunar_atmospheric_tides ,a paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tide

Comment: The Coriolis  force is responsible for weather systems moving from west to east.